# Windows 10 explorer.exe error

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

Whenever I boot up my laptop, the following window opens:

[image]

This is a recent thing - it never used to happen.  Why is it happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: Initially I would download Process Explorer (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), when you next have the error drag the Process Explorer "cross-hairs" icon onto the dialog.  This will highlight the process the dialog belongs to.    You can then see the autorun location under the "Image" tab of the process details, etc..

Comment: Before you spend a lot of time troubleshooting, verify the computer is clean of viruses and malware. I am suspicious of the capital "EXE" in the title of the error window.

Comment: I didn't install anything before this started happening so a virus is highly unlikely, but ive done a virus/malware check anyway and nothing turned up.  I also thought the capitals were suspicious but I looked at the task manager and the dialogue box is from C:\Windows\explorer.exe

Comment: For me it says "Catastrophic failure".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/52f63fb2-387c-4ae1-99c8-5cf996de4c34/windows-8-explorerexe-blank-message-on-startup?forum=w8itprogeneral) or other googlable answers [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/explorer-exe-error-yellow-exclamation-startup-windows-8/) or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psyjltkUPH0).

> 1. Press WinKey + R to bring up the Run menu, type Regedit.exe and press {ENTER}
> 2. Navigate to the following location:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
>   [image]
>
> 3. Double-click Load key and clear the existing value data to set it blank.
> 4. Exit the Registry Editor.

Make sure you have permission to edit the key by clicking menu Edit > Permissions..., then tick the box Full Control in the Allow column > OK.

The name of the key could be Run as well. The value data would be path to some executable in a temp folder usuallly.